# Can I assign the default values to array in bash?

Tags: bash

*** I previously asked a question but it was not the correct question. Now I made the correct question and fixed sample code. And I will up an answer which partially cites an answer to the previous question. ***

I would like to default value to arrays in bash. Please see following,

```
function chmod_chown_func() {
  local file_path="$1"
  local chmod_options[2]=${2:='-R 744'}  # This line has error.
  local chown_options[2]=${3:='-R root:root'}  # This line has error.
  sudo chmod "${chmod_options[@]}" "${file_path}"
  sudo chown "${chown_options[@]}" "${file_path}"
}

chmod_chown_func "test.txt"
```

The error message is

```
$2: cannot assign in this way
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Parameter Expansions

Yes, the expansion `${a:=default}` changes the value of `a`.
It is called `"Assign Default Values"` in the bash manual.

```
$ unset a
$ echo "<${a}>  and  <${a:=default}>, But <${a}>"
<>  and  <default>, But <default>
```

But that syntax could not be applied to positional parameters.
Positional parameters can be (mostly) changed with `set`.

```
$ echo "$@"
a b c
$ set -- d e f
$ echo "$@"
d e f
```

But you can use the expansion of `"Use default value"` as called in the manual:

```
$ unset a
$ echo "<${a}>  and  <${a:-default}>, But <${a}>"
<>  and  <default>, But <>
```

## To assign value(s) to an array variable.

A common idiom is

```
$ array=( aaa bbb ccc )
$ echo "${array[1]}"
bbb
```

Or:

```
$ declare -a array=( aaa bbb ccc )
```

Which also will make the variable local to a function if used inside the function.

However, it comes with the detail that wildcards (`*`, `?` and `[]`) will be expanded (unless quoted or the option `set -f` is used).

Overall, it is better to use `read`:

```
$ IFS=' ' read -a array <<<"$a"
```

## Array index

You can not assign a whole array by using one index. This:

```
chmod_options[2]=${2:-'-R 744'}
```

Will only create **one** array value, at index 2. A better way will be:

```
chmod_options=( ${2:--R 744} )
```

Or, as explained above:

```
IFS=' ' read -a chmod_options <<<"${2:--R 744}"
```

Comment: thank you for telling detailed and better answer about initialization of array with default values.

Answer (score 2):

The follwings are error points and an answer code.

Error 1:
The default value by ${variable:='some value'} does not work with positional parameter.
It should be ${variable:-'some value'}

Error 2:
To assign an default value to an array, declare an array and assign a default array value to it.

An example answer code is following

```
function chmod_chown_func() {
  local file_path="$1"
  local -a chmod_options=${2:-( -R 744 )}
  local -a chown_options=${3:-( -R root:root )}
  sudo chmod "${chmod_options[@]}" "${file_path}"
  sudo chown "${chown_options[@]}" "${file_path}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much luck with the existing answers, so might as well KISS and use a little logic to determine if the array is empty, and then assign the default value if necessary.

```
local -a chmod_options="$2"
local -a chown_options="$3"
# Assign default value if chmod_options is an empty string or array
[[ -z "$chmod_options" || ${#chmod_options[@]} -eq 0 ]] && chmod_options=('-R 744')
# Assign default value if chown_options is an empty string or array
[[ -z "$chown_options" || ${#chown_options[@]} -eq 0 ]] && chown_options=('root:root')
```